# Css - Add line exact under the text in all languages

Tags: css

I need to add line exactly under the text, but it does not work.

```
<h2 class="section-title">Why</h2>
<h2 class="section-title">¿POR QUÉ</h2>


.section-title {
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 60px;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: red;
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mcnika/m4tsL35u/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `text-decoration: underline;` to do that.
Please try the following codes.

```css
.section-title {
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 60px;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: red;
    text-decoration: underline;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="section-title">Why</h2>
<h2 class="section-title">¿POR QUÉ</h2>
```